# getting the total number of categories in store

Tags: category, catalog

what is the best way to get the total number of categories? I'd like to iterate over the total number.

thanks.

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution for your question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following will retrieve a collection of all categories but will only get the total number of records for the categories collection.

This is the lightest way to retrieve the number of categories.

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/category_collection');
print($collection->getSize());
```

Answer (score 0):

You question shows little research effort, however:

```
$categories = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')
```

will return all your categories.

Then `count` them:

```
$count = count($categories)
```

Comment: say we have a million or so categories -- this will iterate over the entire category collection, right?  Is it possible to get the last entry in the DB and get the category_id?  I think that'll be faster..

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Magento has a `getLastItem()` method you could run on the collection, but a million categories that could OOM. You could always use a custom sql query, but not sure what you're trying to accomplish. The normal method for looping categories is above using `foreach ($categories as $category)`

Answer (score -1):

```
select count(*) from catalog_category_entity;
```